# Remove carriage return after div

Tags: html, css

I want to display the "header" div in the same line, but "hdr_menu" div is not on the same line :

```
<div class="container_16">
    <div class="header grid_16">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="./images/logo.png"/>
        </div>
        <div class="header_txt">mywebsite.com</div>
        <div class="hdr_menu">
            <ul>
                <li>Browse</li>
                <li>Login</li>
                <li>Join</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css :

```
.container_16 .grid_16 {
  width: 940px;
}
.header {
height : 100px;
margin-bottom : 10px;
}

.header ul{
margin : 0px;
padding : 0px;
}

.header li{
list-style : none;
display : inline;
margin-left : 10px;
font-size : 20px;
font-family : sans-serif;
}

.hdr_menu{
text-align : right;
margin-top : 0px;
}
.header_txt{
text-align: left;
font-family : sans-serif;
font-size : 200%;
margin-top : 50px;
}
.logo {
float:left;
}
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsbin.com/kazofaxi/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Hashem Qolami this is what I had to add :

```
.header_txt{
text-align: left;
font-family : sans-serif;
font-size : 200%;
margin-top : 50px;
float: left; /*add this line*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.hdr_menu{
text-align : right; //remove
margin-top : 0px;
}

.hdr_menu{
margin-top : 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline;` where you don't want to break the line.